# detached HEAD warning after git rebase

Tags: git, rebase, git-detached-head

My history was

```
P --> A --> revert_A --> B
```

I decided to drop revert_A and squash A and B to have

```
P --> A_squash_B
```

I run `git rebase -i`, drop `revert_A`, squash `B`. The history becomes what I wanted, but with this message

```
$ git rebase -i
[detached HEAD 4cc03a1] check also if error log has been written
 Date: Wed Jan 22 11:44:25 2020 +0100
 2 files changed, 29 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/new_branch.
```

The `4cc03a1` is really the hash of my `A_squash_B`, and it is not detached as it is referenced by `my_branch`.

What does git mean by `[detached HEAD 4cc03a1]`?

Comment: You were on a detached head before you started your rebase operation. (You did `git checkout B` instead of `git checkout my_branch`.)  To fix this, point your branch to the new commit with `git checkout -B my_branch`

Comment: @DavidSugar maybe I don't get what you said, but the changeset `B` is the top of `my_branch` before and after rebasing.

Comment: "detached head" means you are not on a branch.  If you do 'git checkout <commit_id>' you will have  a detached head.  If you do 'git checkout <branch>' you will not have a detached head. If you have a detached head, you can "fix" it by creating a branch for that head with `git checkout -B <branch_name>`

Comment: if your detached head is also the tip of a branch, you can just do `git checkout <branch>`. The point is you must use your branch name  in the `git checkout` command to be on that branch and not have a detached head.  If you do `git checkout <commit_id>`, even if that commit is the tip of a branch, you will be in a detached head state.

Comment: @DavidSugar thanks, but I did not `git checkout` anything, only `git rebase -i`. I know how to fix the detached HEAD issue, just want to know why after `git rebase -i`, a warning "detached HEAD" appeared. Should I understand that my git CLI did include checkout <commit_id> as it should not??? I am using git 2.7.4.

Comment: If you were not in a detached head state before the rebase, you should not be in one after a successful rebase. If that happened, I do not know why.

Comment: "Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/new_branch" means you are on branch `new_branch`. Everything should be fine, shouldn't it?